# php mysql query to return results based on name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table that consists of names, file names and a value. The file name and value are always different. Is it possible to query mysql from php to output the result as a single name and the matching file names and values? The reason for this is I need to create a stacked bar chart using pchart. So I need the names for the axis and the values for the chart data.
The structure of the table:

```
name | file | value
jack | file1.txt | 10
jack | file2.txt | 2
jack | file4.txt | 73
```

Output wanted:

```
array( [Jack] => file1.txt, 10
                 file2.txt, 2
                 file3.txt, 73
      )
```

Currently I'm able to get all the data with a normal query and while loop.
How would I do this?

Comment: Could you elaborate the question more. if possible give the mysql table structure with sample data

Comment: @Ragavendran Ramesh - Just edited the question

Answer (score 1):

You may use **[GROUP_CONCAT(expr)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)** function.

The query would look something like:

```
SELECT
    names,
    GROUP_CONACT( CONCAT( file_names, ",", value ) SEPARATOR "|")
FROM
    myTable
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Working through the notes from the link. Not getting the data output as I wan it but I'm a step further. Thanks Again